# How to fix InvalidParameterValue in PostGIS ST_DWithin() (in rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, postgis

My table is

```
create_table :infomaps do |t|
  t.string :name_station
  t.string :name_location
  t.integer :waterlevel
  t.integer :rain
  t.integer :water_sealevel
  t.integer :tropical_level
  t.integer :bank_level
  t.string :river_name
  t.string :place
  t.st_point :lonlat, geographic: true
  t.integer :time
  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

I would like to use the following example code:

```
SELECT name FROM nyc_streets WHERE ST_DWithin(
    geom,
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(583571 4506714)',26918),
    10
  );
```

with the expected result:

```
 name:Wall St, Broad St and   Nassau St
```

but when trying to do so in ruby on rails, like this:

```
    @result = Infomap.find_by_sql("SELECT name_station FROM infomaps    WHERE ST_DWithin(lonlat,
    ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 100)',26918),
    100); ")
```

I get this error:

```
PG::InvalidParameterValue: ERROR: Only lon/lat coordinate systems are supported in geography. : SELECT name_station FROM infomaps WHERE ST_DWithin(lonlat, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 100)',26918), 100);
```

How do I resolve this `InvalidParameterValue` error for ST_DWithin?

Comment: Your example query and the query in the ruby code are completely different. Use the same query and it will work

Comment: [EPSG:26918](http://epsg.io/26918) is a projected coordinate system, not latitude and longitude, which is expected for the `geography` type.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `geometry` and `geography` types. See this PostGIS [FAQ](http://postgis.net/docs/PostGIS_FAQ.html#idm1018) for a bit more context and links to other more detailed discussions.

When using [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) both parameters must be of the same type. Either `geography` (think lon/lat) or `geometry` in the same projected coordinate system.

Note that you can cast a `geometry` type to `geography` by using the shortcut `::geography` syntax. e.g.

```
SELECT name_station FROM infomaps
    WHERE ST_DWithin(
        lonlat::geography,
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 100)',26918)::geography,
        100);
```

If that doesn't work, try explicitly transforming your geometry point to EPSG code 4326, e.g.

```
SELECT name_station FROM infomaps
    WHERE ST_DWithin(
        lonlat::geography,
        ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 100)', 26918), 4326)::geography,
        100);
```

Or alternatively, convert your lonlat point to the same projected coordinate reference system as your `geometry` point, which should be a bit faster to compute (though potentially negligible depending on your use case):

```
SELECT name_station FROM infomaps
    WHERE ST_DWithin(
        ST_Transform(lonlat, 26918),
        ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20 100)', 26918),
        100);
```